# How to sum distinctly the values of a single column using htsql?

Tags: htsql

I have multiple records in my table's column, most of them are duplicate entries. I want to sum them up so that what ever the number is duplicate should be summed up just once, like:

```
Numbers
10
10
10
15
20
```

The summed result should be `45`
I am using this query:

```
/sum(summary.filter(start_time>='2013-01-01'&end_time<='2013-05-01'&student='john'&course='BCS').s_sub_n)
```

Please help me where I can put `^` to distinct `s_sub_n`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, if I am not getting you wrong, you want the Number column to be distinct and then added.

```
Distinct Number Column(s_sub_n):
10
15
20
```

and then its sum = 45

so the htsql query would be:

```
sum(summary.filter(start_time>='2013-01-01'&end_time<='2013-05-01'&student='john'&course='BCS')^{s_sub_n}{s_sub_n})
```